# For loop gets stuck in a function call in C (cygwin), very weird behavior i couldn't understand

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have this function `someoneDidSomething()`, it's meant to generate a random phrase like "Mandy loved Jesus!" for example.

The problem is, when I call it only one time and exit the program it works just fine. Even if i call the program few times repeatedly. But when I call it in a loop the output looks like the image below.

PS: After some time I get a segmentation fault.

I'm pretty much confused :D - this makes no sense.

```
void main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++)
    {
        char message[255];
        strcpy (message, someoneDidSomething());
        printf ("Because %s\n", message);
        sleep (1);
    }
}

char* someoneDidSomething()
{
    static char message[255];
    strcat (message, getPerson());
    strcat (message, " ");
    strcat (message, getVerb());
    strcat (message, " ");
    strcat (message, getSomething());
    strcat (message, ".");
    return message;
}
```

Called one time output:

```
Because Mandy loved Jesus.
```

Called in a for loop:

```
Because Mandy loved Jesus.Hammond felt the World.Ashlynn knew Jesus.
```

Comment: `static char message[255];
    strcat (message, getPerson());` but `message` isn't initialized.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, but not the cause of the bug.

Comment: @Lundin right. Zero at start, but never cleared. That's the reason of the bug.

Comment: `message` has a length limit of `255`, are you sure you aren't exhausting that limit?

Comment: I switched the first strcat (message, getPerson()); to strcpy (message, getPerson()) and it works perfectly!

Comment: still i don' know how that can make the loop gets stuck in one function

Comment: we dont need to see an image to believe you there is a segfault. Please dont post images of errors, but as plain text.

Comment: @user694733 I'm so sorry i didn't notice, Edited

Comment: @GlenE.Renner don't edit your question with a fixed code. The question made no sense. I reverted it up to dbush revert that meant the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here:

```
static char message[255];
strcat (message, getPerson());
```

the first time it works because global memory (`static` is zeroed in most systems, although adding a `= {0};` doesn't hurt), so `strcat` acts like `strcpy`.

But subsequent calls keep the value in `message`. `message` grows and grows, so not the result you want, and after a while, buffer overflows triggers a segmentation fault.

You need `strcpy` for the first step.

```
static char message[255];
strcpy (message, getPerson());
```

Since you copy the result in the caller, why not passing the buffer directly:

```
    char message[255];
    someoneDidSomething(message);
```

then your routine starts with:

```
void someoneDidSomething(char *message)
{
    strcpy(message, getPerson());
```

you may also consider a single `sprintf` instead of all those function calls...

and doesn't return anything (no need). Also allows your method to be called safely in a multithreaded environment (well safely if the length of the resulting string doesn't exceed the length of the buffer, eternal problem)

Comment: Brilliant! that makes perfect sense now.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Jean-François Fabre, you can fix your program by replacing `static` memory with dynamic memory. Just make sure to free() everything allocated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* someoneDidSomething (void);

int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        char* message = someoneDidSomething();
        printf ("Because %s\n", message);
        free(message);
    }
}

char* someoneDidSomething (void)
{
    char* message = malloc(256);
    message[0] = '\0'; // strcat expects a null terminated string!

    strcat (message, "Bob");
    strcat (message, " ");
    strcat (message, "jumped");
    strcat (message, " ");
    strcat (message, "high");
    strcat (message, ".");

    return message;
}
```

Comment: i had no idea free() function exists :D thanks a lot

Comment: @Lundin in that case, the coolest thing would be to allocate exactly what's needed which can be done by pre-computing the  size. or use non-standard `asprintf`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This code is a simplified version of the OP's code which used functions. I'm not sure that the length can be pre-computed.

Comment: I think it can using `asprintf ("%s %s %s.", getPerson(), getVerb(), getSomething());` or by storing the returned values of each function (unless they're using the same static buffer in which case we're toast :))

Answer (score 0):

you should not declare a static variable. please just try as follow. it would work.

```
char* someoneDidSomething()
{
char message[255]; //just remove static keyword
strcat (message, getPerson());
strcat (message, " ");
strcat (message, getVerb());
strcat (message, " ");
strcat (message, getSomething());
strcat (message, ".");
return message;
}
```